# ActiveSync client Java implementation

Tags: java, client, exchange-server, activesync

My company is working on a project to develop a desktop and mobile email client that can connect to different mail servers with minimal configuration for users or server admins. As we want to support Microsoft Exchange it seems we have to implement the ActiveSync protocol in Java. We're already aware of the licensing issues regarding use of ActiveSync and are in contact with Microsoft.

We've already noticed that Android provides [a partial implementation](http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/exchange/) of what we want to do  but we're looking for a Java library that is more fully featured and easier to integrate into a non-android application.

The solution has to work as a Client, not a server implementation like [DavMail](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/). Basically a Java client implementation of [Z-Push](http://z-push.sourceforge.net/soswp/index.php?pages_id=1&t=home).

Anyone know of anything available?

Answer (score 4):

I've searched extensively as well, and this is the only Java ActiveSync project I've found so far: http://code.google.com/p/synku4j/

Alternatively, you should definitely first look at Microsoft's own Java EWS APIs instead of any commercial product:

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi

Comment: From what I understand, the above 2 options are 2 completely different APIs. One is ActiveSync, and the other is EWS. For what it's worth, it appears that Gmail only supports ActiveSync, and doesn't support EWS, so if your client needs to work with any gmail accounts and sync with Exchange, you should use an ActiveSync solution.