# EAS client in Java

Tags: java, activesync

I am working on a webapp in java that needs to check an Exchange Calendar for updates. As it is relatively mission critical to be up-to-date, I would like to avoid polling and instead go for an ActiveSync connection. Are there libraries for that? Anybody has done that before? I tried googling and only found this:  https://code.google.com/p/synku4j/.

Comment: Oh looky! https://github.com/jimporter/jsas

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030074/activesync-client-java-implementation